# I can,t get menu dropdown when i click on menu button

Tags: jquery

```
        <header class="header-section">
            <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                <ul class="title-area">
                    <li class="name left">
                        <div class="left logo">
                            <div class="left">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo-right_03.png'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo-dot_03.png'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo-left_03.png'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="name">
                        <div class="left logo-text">
                            <h2>Seven<span>Oaks</span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                        <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <ul class="right">

                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/about'); ?>">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/media'); ?>">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/event'); ?>">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/shop'); ?>">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </section>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

I can,t get menu dropdown when i click on menu button. Please help me in this. What i forgot to add? Or anything else. I think i supposed to add some files of javascript in the header but i am not confirm. Please Help me to find my problem.It will be so kinduful for me.

Comment: What is supposed to dropdown? How is it suppposed to dropdown? Is there some javascript that you didn't post? PHP and HTML alone cannot do dropdown menus. You have to use javascript or css to display the dropdown. Where is that code?

Comment: I am using foundation framework to make my site responsive. So when my navigation bar comes in the width of mobile screen then there must be a menu drop down button instead of navigation's options. So when i click on menu button, it doesn't show dropdown list. My Question is which css and javascript files of foundation i supposed to add in my header? And thanks man for reply.!!!

Comment: You probably should have mentioned Foundation Framework in your question and tagged the question with Foundation Framework as well since that's really what you're asking. I've never used Foundation Framework. I use Bootstrap. But here's a link to some tutorials. You can see the required javascript and where they should be placed in the document in the video titled "Foundation Top-Bar Tutorial". http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/tutorials.html

Comment: Thank You So Much brother... I got solution of my problem form this tutorial..It was very kindfull from your side.